# What is Instagram bot request limit?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I wrote a Selenium Script to refresh an instagram user's profile every 30 seconds. After sometime Instagram started throwing me `"Page Not Found"` errors and said `"Please wait a few minutes before you try again"`. I guess this is because of the frequency at which I'm making the bot refresh the page. Does anyone know the allowed request limit per hour or something like that so that I can tune that in?
**I am not using the Instagram API. I am just refreshing the page every 30 seconds. SO it doesn't exceed the 200 requests an hour limit.**

Comment: 200 requests per hour.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm not making 200 requests an hour. 200 was the limit for the API calls.

Comment: this is based on a number of things viz. pattern, action etc. you can refer this repo for Instagram related operations https://github.com/Aqua-4/auto-insta